# Finding the limits of integration for the volume of a region inside a cube

Tags: integration, limits, inequality, definite-integrals, volume

## Premise

We are restricted to the region $x, y, z \in [f, 1]$ where $0 \leq f < 1$. The surface $y^2=4xz$ divides this cube into two regions. We are interested in finding the volume of the region where $y^2 - 4xz \geq 0$.

## My Attempt

Let $t=\frac{y^2}{4}$ for brevity.

When $f=0$, it is relatively easy to figure out the limits. We can separate the region into two where $x \leq t$ and $x > t$. In the first case, we have $y^2 - 4xz \geq 0$ for all $z \in [0, 1]$ because $xz \leq x\cdot 1 \leq t$. Similarly, in the second case, we have $y^2 - 4xz \geq 0$ for all $z \in [0, \frac{t}{x}]$ because $xz \leq x\cdot \frac{t}{x} = t$. Applying these limits, we have

$$
\begin{align}
V &= \int_{0}^{1}{dy\int_{0}^{t}{dx\int_{0}^{1}{dz}}} + \int_{0}^{1}{dy\int_{0}^{t}{dx \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{x}}{dz}}}\\
  &= \int_{0}^{1}{dy\int_{0}^{t}{dx\cdot (1)}} + \int_{0}^{1}{dy\int_{0}^{t}{dx\cdot \frac{t}{x}}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1 + 3\log{2}}{18} \\
  &\approx 0.254
\end{align}
$$

However, when $f > 0$, I cannot seem to understand the proper limits for $z$. Is it $f$ to $\frac{t}{x}$ or is the lower limit $f^2$? What happens when $f$ is less than or equal to $\frac{y^2}{4}$?

I tried a few times, but the results ended up being negative, which is clearly wrong as volumes are nonnegative.

## Specific Questions

### Primary objective

I would like help in figuring out the limits in the case where $f>0$.

### Secondary objectives

1. Is this approach sensible? Perhaps there is a better way to solve this problem?
2. Are there any glaring oversights?
3. What books/courses/reference should I follow to be able to solve these types of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to find the volume of the cube formed by $x, y, z \in [f, 1], 0 \leq f \lt 1$, with the condition $y^2 \geq 4xz$ (outside the cone).

For the cube, the upper limit for $x, y, z$ is $1$.

For the cone, please note when $x = z = 1, y = 2$ (I am only considering first octant given our cube is in the first octant) but as we are restricted by $y = 1$ for the cube, we have $4xz \leq 1 \implies x, z \leq  \min (\frac{1}{4f}, 1)$ for $f \ne 0$.

At the same time for the points outside the cone, $y^2 \geq 4f^2 \implies y \geq 2f$ for $x = z = f$ and $y \geq 2 \sqrt f \ \gt f $ as $f \lt 1$ for $x = 1, z = f$ or $z = 1, x = f$.

These are important observations to find the right limits for our volume integral. What it indicates is that if $f \leq 0.25, $ we have following $3$ vertices of the cube outside the cone and rest $5$ are inside -

$(f,1,f),(f,1,1), (1,1,f)$

In fact at $f = 0.25$, $(f,1,1)$ and $(1,1,f)$ are on the cone and only $(f,1,f)$ is outside.

Also note that at $f = 0.5$, $(f,1,f)$ is on the cone and rest are inside and so for $f \geq 0.5$, we have not volume bound (as all points of the cube are inside the cone, $y^2 \leq 4xz$).

So here is the integral to find the desired volume

i) $0 \leq f \leq 0.25$ (first integral is zero at $f = 0.25$)

$\displaystyle  \int_{f}^{0.25} \int_{f}^{1} \int_{2\sqrt{xz}}^{1} dy \ dx \ dz + 
\int_{0.25}^{1} \int_{f}^{1/(4z)} \int_{2\sqrt{xz}}^{1} dy \ dx \ dz$

And your answer is indeed correct for $f = 0$.

ii) $0.25 \leq f \leq 0.5$ (zero for $f = 0.5$)

$\displaystyle \int_{f}^{1/(4f)} \int_{f}^{1/(4z)} \int_{2\sqrt{xz}}^{1} \ dy \ dx \ dz$

To your other specific questions, no there does not seem anything wrong with your approach. But your approach did not extend to other cases, probably because you did not visualize the surface well enough. A $3D$ sketch using an online tool helps. I literally had to keep a cube in front of me while answering the question.

Comment: @HungryBlueDev do you have any questions on this?

Comment: No, sorry for the delay, I'm working it out myself. I'll accept your answer soon!

Comment: @HungryBlueDev thanks for your response. Accepting it or not is your prerogative, based on whether you deem the answer good enough. As I did not hear, I was wondering if I was clear in my answer or not. If you are working on it yourself, you may want to use a 3D online visualization tool where you can try and put different values of $f$ and see how the intersection changes.

Comment: I am trying to evaluate the integral but I'm making calculation mistakes. This is on me and not on you. Please don't feel bad, I am just bad at integration.

Comment: I finally evaluated the integrals correctly. :-) Btw I want to include your answer as a part of a paper. Please [contact me](https://hungrybluedev.in/contact/) so that I can include your name in it.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. As far as the paper goes, you can now form your own answer based on your own understanding. So it is alright. I would rather remain anonymous on this site :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll definitely cite this answer though. Here's a [plot](https://imgur.com/hWke8df) showing how your answer matches the actual result.