# Finding the volume of $z^2<4xy$ if $x,y,z \in [0,1]$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to know how to find the volume beneath $z^2=4xy$, given that $x,y,z \in [0,1]$.

My first thoughts are to find:

$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 2\sqrt{x \cdot y}dx dy
$$

But this gives a value that is too large since it doesn't include the restriction that $z\in[0,1]$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Split into 2 regions, one where the height is $2\sqrt{xy} \leq 1$, and the other where the height is $1$.

Comment: Why did you use the bounds $0 \lt x \lt 1$ and $0 \lt y \lt 1$? Is the projection of the region in xy-plane a unit square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As clarified, your question is to find the volume of the region inside the cube $[0, 1]^3$ below $z^2 = 4xy$. One way is to first find the volume bound above the unit square $[0, 1]^2$ in xy-plane and then subtract the volume above the unshaded part and above $z = 1$.

So the integral will be,

$ \displaystyle V_1 = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 2 \sqrt{xy} ~dx ~dy$

$\displaystyle V_2 = \int_{1/4}^1 \int_{1/(4y)}^1 (2 \sqrt{xy} - 1) ~dx ~dy$

And finally $V = V_1 - V_2$

Comment: You have to include the white part in the square as well, where the height is a uniform 1.

Comment: @Paul that's not directly beneath the surface $z^2 = 4xy$

Comment: In other words, the way you are interpreting it is the volume of the cube $[0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ intersected by cone $z^2 \leq 4 xy$ and that may be the case but given the question, I interpreted it the way I did.

Comment: @MathLover thank you very much this is exactly what I was trying to get. For context, yes, I am trying to find a volume within a cube.

Comment: @MathLover My primary struggle is finding the bounds of integration. If I wanted to extend this problem to the volume within $z^2=4xy$, for $x,y,z \in [-1,1]^3$, how would I find the bounds of integration ?

Comment: @FISR I updated it for volume inside the cube. If you extend it to $x, y, z \in [-1, 1]^3$, you just need to multiply by $4$ as the cone forms only in $4$ of the $8$ octants.

Comment: @FISR I solved a problem of the same cone inside a cube sometime ago, though a little complicated than this. You may want to look at it (there the cone is $y^2 = 4xz$) - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000248/finding-the-limits-of-integration-for-the-volume-of-a-region-inside-a-cube

Comment: @MathLover Thank you, I suspect my problem is very similar to the one you've solved there. For the second integral, why do we subtract 1 and how do you derive the lower bounds for the integral ?

Comment: @FISR for the lower bounds, what is the intersection of plane $z = 1$ and surface $z^2 = 4xy$? Plugging in $z = 1,$ it is curve $4xy = 1$. Now for the second integral (unshaded part in my diagram), $4xy \geq 1 1$. So if we integrate wrt $dx$ first, the lower bound of $x$ is $1 / (4y)$. For the lower bound of $y$, what is the intersection of curve $4xy = 1$ and $x = 1$?Plug in $x = 1$ and we get $y = 1/4$. As $z \leq 1$, we want to subtract the volume above $z = 1$ and below $z^2 = 4xy$. That is why $2 \sqrt{xy} - 1$.